# What is docker image reference?

Tags: docker

Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) mentions image reference in many places. However, running `docker images` command gives the list of images with the following properties: REPOSITORY, TAG, IMAGE ID, CREATED, SIZE - no reference. Is 'reference' a synonym for ID or digest, or something else?

Comment: it's the repository + tag. example: `busybox:latest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker image reference is the combination of the REPOSITORY and TAG in this format `REPOSITORY:TAG` where they are both separated by `:`. So if  you have an image with a REPOSITORY of `IMAGE1` and a tag of `latest` the image reference would be `IMAGE1:latest`. The knowledge of an image reference would help you to filter by docker image list by reference by running:

```sh
docker images --filter=reference='myDocker*:*dev'
```

The above command will return all docker images that the repository name starts with `myDocker` and the tag name ends with `dev`.

Comment: Be careful with wildcards: for "directories", i.e. anything between 2 `/`, you have to use `**` instead of `*`

Comment: @Marcel makes a great point, but don't take this advice. There is no support for `**` patterns. There is an open issue in moby/moby to add it. You have to do `*/*/*:*`, and if you don't know how many slashes you have, then it's a won't-fix kind of limitation.

Comment: @AlanSE can you link the issue?

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Kelvin's answer, `Reference` is the `Repository` which you will use with the `tag`. Have a look the below example.

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
busybox             latest              e02e811dd08f        5 weeks ago         1.09 MB
busybox             uclibc              e02e811dd08f        5 weeks ago         1.09 MB
busybox             musl                733eb3059dce        5 weeks ago         1.21 MB
busybox             glibc               21c16b6787c6        5 weeks ago         4.19 MB
```

As you can see above, my reference would be respectively

```
busybox:latest
busybox:uclibc
busybox:musl
busybox:glibc
```

If you only use the reference as `busybox`, by default it will use the `latest` tag.

You can filter the images on the reference filter as well.

```
docker images --filter=reference='busy*:*libc'
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
busybox             uclibc              e02e811dd08f        5 weeks ago         1.09 MB
busybox             glibc               21c16b6787c6        5 weeks ago         4.19 MB
```

You use the image reference in `Dockerfile` as well when you build the image by using the `FROM` directive.

```
FROM busybox #Reference is used as you can see and automatically, `latest` tag will be pulled
...
```

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/
>
> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from